# Prevent mouse capture in moaco editor if editor is not scrollable

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

I want to disable mouse capture in monaco editor in case that the content inside is not scrollable as it creates a part of the page which is impossible to scroll past of, i found the `alwaysConsumeMouseWheel` but i can't seem to find a way to enable this at "runtime", is there a setting or someway i could make this work?

Comment: "_a part of the page which is impossible to scroll past of_" can you add a screenshot with a circle around this "part"?

Comment: @starball it's the whole editor, I was just describing the experience of the user being stuck not able to scroll